# Filling in date gaps in MultiIndex Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multi-index

I would like to modify a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame such that each index group includes Dates between a specified range. I would like each group to fill in missing dates 2013-06-11 to 2013-12-31 with the value 0 (or `NaN`).

```
Group A, Group B, Date,           Value
loc_a    group_a  2013-06-11      22
                  2013-07-02      35
                  2013-07-09      14
                  2013-07-30       9
                  2013-08-06       4
                  2013-09-03      40
                  2013-10-01      18
         group_b  2013-07-09       4
                  2013-08-06       2
                  2013-09-03       5
         group_c  2013-07-09       1
                  2013-09-03       2
loc_b    group_a  2013-10-01       3
```

I've seen a few discussions of `reindex`ing, but that is for a simple (non-grouped) time-series data.

Is there an easy way to do this?

---

Following are some attempts I've made at accomplishing this.  For example: Once I've unstacked by `['A', 'B']`, I can then reindex.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['loc_a'] * 12 + ['loc_b'],
                'B': ['group_a'] * 7 + ['group_b'] * 3 + ['group_c'] * 2 + ['group_a'],
                'Date': ["2013-06-11",
                        "2013-07-02",
                        "2013-07-09",
                        "2013-07-30",
                        "2013-08-06",
                        "2013-09-03",
                        "2013-10-01",
                        "2013-07-09",
                        "2013-08-06",
                        "2013-09-03",
                        "2013-07-09",
                        "2013-09-03",
                        "2013-10-01"],
                 'Value': [22, 35, 14,  9,  4, 40, 18, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]})

df.Date = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date())
df = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'Date'])

dt_start = dt.datetime(2013,6,1)
all_dates = [(dt_start + dt.timedelta(days=x)).date() for x in range(0,60)]

df2 = df.unstack(['A', 'B'])
df3 = df2.reindex(index=all_dates).fillna(0)
df4 = df3.stack(['A', 'B'])

## df4 is about where I want to get, now I'm trying to get it back in the form of df...

df5 = df4.reset_index()
df6 = df5.rename(columns={'level_0' : 'Date'})
df7 = df6.groupby(['A', 'B', 'Date'])['Value'].sum()
```

The last few lines make me a little sad. I was hoping that at `df6` I could simply `set_index` back to `['A', 'B', 'Date']`, but that did not group the values as they are grouped in the initial `df` DataFrame.

Any thoughts on how I can reindex the unstacked DataFrame, restack, and have the DataFrame in the same format as the original?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your question wasn't clear about exactly which dates you were missing;  I'm just assuming that you want to fill `NaN` for any date for which you *do* have an observation elsewhere.  My solution will have to be amended if this assumption is faulty.

Side note: it may be nice to include a line to create the `DataFrame`

```
In [55]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['loc_a'] * 12 + ['loc_b'],
   ....:                    'B': ['group_a'] * 7 + ['group_b'] * 3 + ['group_c'] * 2 + ['group_a'],
   ....:                    'Date': ["2013-06-11",
   ....:                            "2013-07-02",
   ....:                            "2013-07-09",
   ....:                            "2013-07-30",
   ....:                            "2013-08-06",
   ....:                            "2013-09-03",
   ....:                            "2013-10-01",
   ....:                            "2013-07-09",
   ....:                            "2013-08-06",
   ....:                            "2013-09-03",
   ....:                            "2013-07-09",
   ....:                            "2013-09-03",
   ....:                            "2013-10-01"],
   ....:                     'Value': [22, 35, 14,  9,  4, 40, 18, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]})

In [56]: 

In [56]: df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

In [57]: df = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'Date'])

In [58]: 

In [58]: print(df)
                          Value
A     B       Date             
loc_a group_a 2013-06-11     22
              2013-07-02     35
              2013-07-09     14
              2013-07-30      9
              2013-08-06      4
              2013-09-03     40
              2013-10-01     18
      group_b 2013-07-09      4
              2013-08-06      2
              2013-09-03      5
      group_c 2013-07-09      1
              2013-09-03      2
loc_b group_a 2013-10-01      3
```

To get the unobserved values filled, we'll use the `unstack` and `stack` methods.  Unstacking will create the `NaN`s we're interested in, and then we'll stack them up to work with.

```
In [71]: df.unstack(['A', 'B'])
Out[71]: 
              Value                           
A             loc_a                      loc_b
B           group_a  group_b  group_c  group_a
Date                                          
2013-06-11       22      NaN      NaN      NaN
2013-07-02       35      NaN      NaN      NaN
2013-07-09       14        4        1      NaN
2013-07-30        9      NaN      NaN      NaN
2013-08-06        4        2      NaN      NaN
2013-09-03       40        5        2      NaN
2013-10-01       18      NaN      NaN        3


In [59]: df.unstack(['A', 'B']).fillna(0).stack(['A', 'B'])
Out[59]: 
                          Value
Date       A     B             
2013-06-11 loc_a group_a     22
                 group_b      0
                 group_c      0
           loc_b group_a      0
2013-07-02 loc_a group_a     35
                 group_b      0
                 group_c      0
           loc_b group_a      0
2013-07-09 loc_a group_a     14
                 group_b      4
                 group_c      1
           loc_b group_a      0
2013-07-30 loc_a group_a      9
                 group_b      0
                 group_c      0
           loc_b group_a      0
2013-08-06 loc_a group_a      4
                 group_b      2
                 group_c      0
           loc_b group_a      0
2013-09-03 loc_a group_a     40
                 group_b      5
                 group_c      2
           loc_b group_a      0
2013-10-01 loc_a group_a     18
                 group_b      0
                 group_c      0
           loc_b group_a      3
```

Reorder the index levels as necessary.

I had to slip that `fillna(0)` in the middle there so that the `NaN`s weren't dropped.  `stack` does have a `dropna` argument.  I would think that setting that to false would keep the all `NaN` rows around.  A bug maybe?

Comment: FWIW, the dropna argument to stack() is working for me with pandas 0.16.2

Answer (score 41):

You can make a new multi index based on the Cartesian product of the levels of the existing multi index. Then, re-index your data frame using the new index.

```python
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)
new_df = df.reindex(new_index)

# Optional: convert missing values to zero, and convert the data back
# to integers. See explanation below.
new_df = new_df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

That's it! The new data frame has all the possible index values. The existing data is indexed correctly.

Read on for a more detailed explanation.

---

### Explanation

#### Set up sample data

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['loc_a'] * 12 + ['loc_b'],
                   'B': ['group_a'] * 7 + ['group_b'] * 3 + ['group_c'] * 2 + ['group_a'],
                   'Date': ["2013-06-11",
                           "2013-07-02",
                           "2013-07-09",
                           "2013-07-30",
                           "2013-08-06",
                           "2013-09-03",
                           "2013-10-01",
                           "2013-07-09",
                           "2013-08-06",
                           "2013-09-03",
                           "2013-07-09",
                           "2013-09-03",
                           "2013-10-01"],
                    'Value': [22, 35, 14,  9,  4, 40, 18, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]})

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'Date'])
```

Here's what the sample data looks like

```
                          Value
A     B       Date
loc_a group_a 2013-06-11     22
              2013-07-02     35
              2013-07-09     14
              2013-07-30      9
              2013-08-06      4
              2013-09-03     40
              2013-10-01     18
      group_b 2013-07-09      4
              2013-08-06      2
              2013-09-03      5
      group_c 2013-07-09      1
              2013-09-03      2
loc_b group_a 2013-10-01      3
```

#### Make new index

Using [from_product](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) we can make a new multi index. This new index is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all the values from all the levels of the old index.

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)
```

#### Reindex

Use the new index to reindex the existing data frame.

```
new_df = df.reindex(new_index)
```

All the possible combinations are now present. The missing values are null (NaN).

The expanded, re-indexed data frame looks like this:

```
                          Value
loc_a group_a 2013-06-11   22.0
              2013-07-02   35.0
              2013-07-09   14.0
              2013-07-30    9.0
              2013-08-06    4.0
              2013-09-03   40.0
              2013-10-01   18.0
      group_b 2013-06-11    NaN
              2013-07-02    NaN
              2013-07-09    4.0
              2013-07-30    NaN
              2013-08-06    2.0
              2013-09-03    5.0
              2013-10-01    NaN
      group_c 2013-06-11    NaN
              2013-07-02    NaN
              2013-07-09    1.0
              2013-07-30    NaN
              2013-08-06    NaN
              2013-09-03    2.0
              2013-10-01    NaN
loc_b group_a 2013-06-11    NaN
              2013-07-02    NaN
              2013-07-09    NaN
              2013-07-30    NaN
              2013-08-06    NaN
              2013-09-03    NaN
              2013-10-01    3.0
      group_b 2013-06-11    NaN
              2013-07-02    NaN
              2013-07-09    NaN
              2013-07-30    NaN
              2013-08-06    NaN
              2013-09-03    NaN
              2013-10-01    NaN
      group_c 2013-06-11    NaN
              2013-07-02    NaN
              2013-07-09    NaN
              2013-07-30    NaN
              2013-08-06    NaN
              2013-09-03    NaN
              2013-10-01    NaN
```

#### Nulls in integer column

You can see that the data in the new data frame has been converted from ints to floats. [Pandas can't have nulls in an integer column](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na). Optionally, we can convert all the nulls to 0, and cast the data back to integers.

```
new_df = new_df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Result

```
                          Value
loc_a group_a 2013-06-11     22
              2013-07-02     35
              2013-07-09     14
              2013-07-30      9
              2013-08-06      4
              2013-09-03     40
              2013-10-01     18
      group_b 2013-06-11      0
              2013-07-02      0
              2013-07-09      4
              2013-07-30      0
              2013-08-06      2
              2013-09-03      5
              2013-10-01      0
      group_c 2013-06-11      0
              2013-07-02      0
              2013-07-09      1
              2013-07-30      0
              2013-08-06      0
              2013-09-03      2
              2013-10-01      0
loc_b group_a 2013-06-11      0
              2013-07-02      0
              2013-07-09      0
              2013-07-30      0
              2013-08-06      0
              2013-09-03      0
              2013-10-01      3
      group_b 2013-06-11      0
              2013-07-02      0
              2013-07-09      0
              2013-07-30      0
              2013-08-06      0
              2013-09-03      0
              2013-10-01      0
      group_c 2013-06-11      0
              2013-07-02      0
              2013-07-09      0
              2013-07-30      0
              2013-08-06      0
              2013-09-03      0
              2013-10-01      0
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I did lose the names of the indices, but that means we're looking at 3 lines of code instead of 2...

Comment: OK, 4 lines of code:

    `index_names = df.index.names`
    `new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)`
    `new_index.names = index_names`
    `new_df = df.reindex(tmp_new_index).fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: [pd.MultiIndex.from_product()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) takes a `names` positional arg, so: `new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)`