# reindex multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Regards.

I'm Struggling trying to figure out how to do the next operation in pandas:

I have a csv file with timestamps of stations like the following:

[head of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFsaP.png)

The next thing I do is the following pivot_table using pandas:

```
trips.pivot_table('bike', aggfunc='count',
                        index=['date', 'hour'],
                        columns='station_arrived').fillna(0)
```

returning something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJkij.png)

My Problem is the following:

I want to reindex the 'hour' column to have indexes from 0 to 23 hours per day, even if there aren't counts that day.

Doing reindex with only one index is easy, but things get complicated when I'm trying this in a multiindex dataframe

Is there any way to make that possible?

Comment: I think you will need to create the empty rows before you make the pivot table. So that would involve coming up with a method to check, for each index, which hours are missing, then generate rows for that index with 0/null values for the missing hours. THEN create the pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'action': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
     'bike': [89, 89, 57, 29, 76, 69, 17],
     'cust_id': [6, 6, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
     'date': [Timestamp('2010-02-02 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2010-02-02 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2010-02-05 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2010-02-05 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2010-02-05 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2010-02-05 00:00:00'),
              Timestamp('2010-02-05 00:00:00')],
     'date_arrived': [Timestamp('2010-02-02 14:27:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-02 15:42:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 12:06:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 12:07:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 13:11:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 13:14:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 13:45:00')],
     'date_removed': [Timestamp('2010-02-02 13:57:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-02 15:12:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 11:36:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 11:37:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 12:41:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 12:44:00'),
                      Timestamp('2010-02-05 13:15:00')],
     'hour': [14, 15, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13],
     'station_arrived': [56, 56, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85],
     'station_removed': [56, 56, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85]})
```

First, create an hourly index spanning your date range:

```
idx = pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max() + dt.timedelta(days=1), freq='H')
```

Now you want to have a datetime index, so set it to 'date_arrived'.  Then use `groupby` with both `TimeGrouper` to group on hours and on `station_arrived`.  `count` the number of non-null `station_arrived` values.  Unstack the results to get the data in the pivot table format.

Finally, use `reindex` to set the index on your new hourly interval `idx` index, and fill null values with zero.

```
>>> (df
     .set_index('date_arrived')
     .groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('H'), 'station_arrived'])
     .station_arrived
     .count()
     .unstack()
     .reindex(idx)
     .fillna(0)
     )
station_arrived      56  85
2010-02-02 00:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 01:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 02:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 03:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 04:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 05:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 06:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 07:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 08:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 09:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 10:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 11:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 12:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 13:00:00   0   0
2010-02-02 14:00:00   1   0
2010-02-02 15:00:00   1   0
2010-02-02 16:00:00   0   0
...
```

Comment: Very impresive and fancy method!
I was reading a similar method from this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287933/filling-in-date-gaps-in-multiindex-pandas-dataframe?rq=1

pointing to the unstack could be a solution but yours just solved it perfectly. 

Thank you! And sorry for not be able to upvote your solution. not enough points to do so.