# Fill gaps in DataFrame MultiIndex level 1, differently for each level 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex DataFrame with gappy date values on level 1, like this:

```
np.random.seed(456)
j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C'] for b in random.sample(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='D').tolist(), 5)]
j.sort()
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(j, names=['Name','Date'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,100,15), i, columns=['Vals'])
# print(df):
                 Vals
Name Date            
A    2018-01-01    27
     2018-01-08    43
     2018-03-26    89
     2018-03-29    42
     2018-04-01    28
B    2018-01-02    79
     2018-01-26    60
     2018-02-18    45
     2018-03-11    37
     2018-03-23    92
C    2018-03-17    39
     2018-03-20    81
     2018-03-21    11
     2018-03-27    77
     2018-04-08    69
```

For each level 0 value, I want to fill in the index level 1 with every calendar date between the min and max date values *for that level 0*.  ([This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17287933/2662901) addresses the scenario of filling in level 1 with the *same* value set for all level 0 values.)

E.g., for `subset = df.loc['A']` I want to insert rows so that `subset.index.values == pd.date_range(subset.index.values.min(), subset.index.values.max()).values`.  I.e., the resulting DataFrame would look like:

```
                 Vals
Name Date            
A    2018-01-01    27
     2018-01-02   NaN
     2018-01-03   NaN
     2018-01-04   NaN
     2018-01-05   NaN
     2018-01-06   NaN
     2018-01-07   NaN
     2018-01-08    43
     2018-01-09   NaN
...
```

Is there a pandaic way to accomplish this?

(The best I can come up with is to inefficiently and iteratively [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) new DataFrames for each level 0 value.  Or similarly iteratively construct a list of index values and then [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) them with the original DataFrame.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `asfreq`

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).asfreq("D"))
```

Comment: This is clever !

Comment: Damn ... brilliant!  This is why I worry anytime I'm using more than one line of python to do something ;)

Comment: @feetwet sometime multiple line is good for reading and speed:-)