# Pandas Multiindex Series Level Reindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, reindex

I have the **ser_apl** pandas.Series with 2-level MultiIndex:

```
Date        Team     
2013-01-31  Man Utd      11
2013-02-28  Man Utd      12
2013-03-29  Man Utd      13
2013-04-30  Man Utd      14
2013-05-31  Man Utd      15
2013-06-28  Man Utd      16
2013-07-31  Man Utd      17
2013-08-30  Man Utd      18
2013-09-30  Man Utd      19
2013-10-31  Man Utd      20
2013-11-29  Man Utd      21
2013-12-31  Man Utd      22
2013-07-31  Liverpool    37
2013-08-30  Liverpool    38
2013-09-30  Liverpool    39
2013-10-31  Liverpool    40
2013-11-29  Liverpool    41
2013-12-31  Liverpool    42
2013-01-31  Chelsea      51
2013-02-28  Chelsea      52
2013-03-29  Chelsea      53
2013-04-30  Chelsea      54
2013-05-31  Chelsea      55
2013-06-28  Chelsea      56
Name: Result, dtype: int64
```

I need to reindex **Date** level for all teams to receive:

```
Date        Team     
2013-01-31  Chelsea      51.0
2013-02-28  Chelsea      52.0
2013-03-29  Chelsea      53.0
2013-04-30  Chelsea      54.0
2013-05-31  Chelsea      55.0
2013-06-28  Chelsea      56.0
2013-07-31  Chelsea       NaN
2013-08-30  Chelsea       NaN
2013-09-30  Chelsea       NaN
2013-10-31  Chelsea       NaN
2013-11-29  Chelsea       NaN
2013-12-31  Chelsea       NaN
2013-01-31  Liverpool     NaN
2013-02-28  Liverpool     NaN
2013-03-29  Liverpool     NaN
2013-04-30  Liverpool     NaN
2013-05-31  Liverpool     NaN
2013-06-28  Liverpool     NaN
2013-07-31  Liverpool    37.0
2013-08-30  Liverpool    38.0
2013-09-30  Liverpool    39.0
2013-10-31  Liverpool    40.0
2013-11-29  Liverpool    41.0
2013-12-31  Liverpool    42.0
2013-01-31  Man Utd      11.0
2013-02-28  Man Utd      12.0
2013-03-29  Man Utd      13.0
2013-04-30  Man Utd      14.0
2013-05-31  Man Utd      15.0
2013-06-28  Man Utd      16.0
2013-07-31  Man Utd      17.0
2013-08-30  Man Utd      18.0
2013-09-30  Man Utd      19.0
2013-10-31  Man Utd      20.0
2013-11-29  Man Utd      21.0
2013-12-31  Man Utd      22.0
dtype: float64
```

First of all I prepared index:

```
idx_level_date = ser_apl.index.get_level_values('Date').unique()
```

Then I tried a couple of ways:

```
ser_apl.reindex(idx_level_date, level = 'Date')
```

and as alternative:

```
ser_apl.groupby('Team').apply(lambda iter_team: iter_team.reindex(idx_level_date, level = 'Date'))
```

Both was unsuccessful:
result was the same as original ser_apl.

So I need help for reindexing.

P.S. I found the alternative unstack/stack trick here: [Filling in date gaps in MultiIndex Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287933/filling-in-date-gaps-in-multiindex-pandas-dataframe?rq=1)

But the question is why I can't do the same thing with appropriate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create all possible datetimes by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and pass to [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), if necessary, change ordering by [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(ser_apl.index.levels, names=ser_apl.index.names)
s = ser_apl.reindex(mux).sort_index(level=[1,0])
```

---

```
print (s)
Date        Team     
2013-01-31  Chelsea      51.0
2013-02-28  Chelsea      52.0
2013-03-29  Chelsea      53.0
2013-04-30  Chelsea      54.0
2013-05-31  Chelsea      55.0
2013-06-28  Chelsea      56.0
2013-07-31  Chelsea       NaN
2013-08-30  Chelsea       NaN
2013-09-30  Chelsea       NaN
2013-10-31  Chelsea       NaN
2013-11-29  Chelsea       NaN
2013-12-31  Chelsea       NaN
2013-01-31  Liverpool     NaN
2013-02-28  Liverpool     NaN
2013-03-29  Liverpool     NaN
2013-04-30  Liverpool     NaN
2013-05-31  Liverpool     NaN
2013-06-28  Liverpool     NaN
2013-07-31  Liverpool    37.0
2013-08-30  Liverpool    38.0
2013-09-30  Liverpool    39.0
2013-10-31  Liverpool    40.0
2013-11-29  Liverpool    41.0
2013-12-31  Liverpool    42.0
2013-01-31  Man Utd      11.0
2013-02-28  Man Utd      12.0
2013-03-29  Man Utd      13.0
2013-04-30  Man Utd      14.0
2013-05-31  Man Utd      15.0
2013-06-28  Man Utd      16.0
2013-07-31  Man Utd      17.0
2013-08-30  Man Utd      18.0
2013-09-30  Man Utd      19.0
2013-10-31  Man Utd      20.0
2013-11-29  Man Utd      21.0
2013-12-31  Man Utd      22.0
Name: Result, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but what is wrong with reindex method?

Comment: @igharok - If MultiIndex is necesary use `reindex` with both levels of MultiIndex

Comment: @YOBEN_S I'm closing this case, but it seems strange that _level_ is de facto fake  parameter of reindex method.